# How can I run a script that starts before my login screen?

Tags: x11, startup, session

I was calibrating my touch screen, and saw that the best tool around was xinput_calibrator. So I used it. It have two options (one of which did not work), so I am here for the second. It says I should execute this command "in a script that starts with your X session":

`xinput set-int-prop "3M 3M USB Touchscreen - EX II" "Evdev Axis Calibration" 32 14410 2146 14574 2115`

So I tried `~/.xinitrc`, `~/.xsession` and `~/.xsessionrc`, all of which did not exist. So I created them and the exact content was this command. The first two files made my logins fail (after I login, I fall back to the login screen).

With the last file, the calibration was functional, but only after logging in...

I need that command to run **before** the login dialog shows up. I thought of adding this command to the end of `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` with no result (nothing changed). Also, I tried to add it to the end of `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/40x11-common_xsessionrc` (after inspecting some of the files), but the result was exactly the same as adding it to `~/.xsessionrc`.

How can I make this command run before the login screen shows (is this before the window manager starts, or before the X session starts)?

(I am running Kubuntu with the default window manager, if that matters)

**UPDATE** As I am using Kubuntu, my display manager is kdm. As the accepted answer suggests, I edited the file `/etc/kde4/kdm/Xsetup`, and as mentioned [here](http://maketecheasier.com/run-startup-scripts-in-kdm-before-kde-starts/2011/12/15) I added the command before the command that is there by default. And it works like a charm :)

Comment: What login manager are you using? For gdm3 you can probably use `/etc/gdm3/Init/display` or `/etc/gdm3/Init/Default` - http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=gdm3&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+6.0+squeeze&format=html&locale=en

Comment: Hey, good stuff. I've posted a question here [http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172007/linux-mint-17-cinnamon-how-can-i-run-an-application-prior-to-the-login-screen] which got marked as a possible duplicate to this Q&A. However, folks, am not convinced it's a clone. Pl see my question too and help me out :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All the files you tried to change are read after you log in. Furthermore, `~/.xinitrc` and `~/.xsession` are the full set of commands that run in a session; `~/.xinitrc` is read if you run `xinit` or `startx` from a text mode prompt, and `~/.xsession` is read if you run a “custom session” (the name may vary) from a graphical login prompt.

You need to configure your [display manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_%28program_type%29), the program that shows the login prompt. For kdm, the KDE display manager, add your command to `/etc/kde4/kdm/Xsetup` (or `/etc/kde3/kdm/Xsetup` for older versions) (that's the path on Debian, I haven't verified that Kubuntu uses the same path).

For gdm (the Gnome display manager), add your command to `/etc/gdm/Init/Default`. For xdm (the traditional X display manager), add your command to `/etc/X11/xdm/Xsetup`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I tried what you suggested without success. I located the `Xsetup` file (in the same path you mentioned) and added the command. The calibration did not work, but I made sure it was executed, by adding `echo "w" > /test.log`, and verifying `/test.log` did exist after reboot. Is it possible that `xinput` requires special "context" or something... ?

Comment: Actually, disregard the last comment. I redirected the `xinput` command to that file, and it seems I had added a space to the device name which made the calibration not work. You were 100% correct :) Thanks again.

Comment: And just to complete the answer - to find out what is your display manager (not to be confused with a desktop environment) use: `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`.

Comment: What about `xserverrc`? And the ones that are in `/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc`?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai `xserverrc` is executed by `startx`. Since it runs before the X server start (actually, its job is to start the X server), it wouldn't have been of any use here.

Comment: Doesn't the display manager itself need an X server to display anything? I feel like you're talking about having an X server after the display manager, whereas I thought the X server needs to be available before the display manager?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai If there's a display manager, `startx` is not used. Display manager initialization scripts would not be relevant here since they run before the user logs in.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you create your own config file, a simple example:

```
/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-calibration.conf
```

Filecontent:

```
Section "InputClass"
         Identifier "Calibration"
         MatchProduct "3M 3M USB Touchscreen - EX II"
         Option "Calibration" "14410 2146 14574 2115"
EndSection
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

You could try  /etc/rc.local ?

.

Comment: I was concerned the script would run before X even starts (as I understood it), which would render that script useless... When does this run?

Comment: @jadkik94 you are right this won't work as rc.local doesn't have access to the x session.

Answer (score -1):

When you have OpenSUSE you can copy your script to /etc/init.d and run insserv script name. insserv enables a script: http://man-wiki.net/index.php/8:insserv.

Comment: This probably won't work as `xinput` needs probably X which is not available/initialized in the init scripts