# Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon: how can I run an application prior to the login screen?

Tags: linux-mint, login, mdm

I'd like to run an app (Python Tk, say) *prior* to the login screen on LMC 17. I notice that there's plenty of Q&A on doing this on Ubuntu ([here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1851805), for eg), but couldn't really find anything relevant on Linux Mint.

Any ideas?

**[UPDATE]**
Okay, I do see that the qs is very similar to the one pointed out by several folks. *However*, I still don't find an answer particularly pertaining to the Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon display manager -  which appears to be **mdm** :

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Linux Mint 17 Qiana \n \l
$ cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 
/usr/sbin/mdm
$
```

So, particularly, how do I leverage (or otherwise) use mdm to run an app prior to login? 
Note, for this to be useful: the app itself is graphical, hence X should be running by this point..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I got an answer from [mtwebster](https://github.com/mtwebster) [here](http://segfault.linuxmint.com/2014/10/better-looking-mdm-setup/) (see the comments), which I feel is the "right" answer :

Check out this file: https://github.com/linuxmint/mdm/blob/master/config/Init.in

This runs before the greeter in MDM (if you look at the recent commit there, we added syndaemon to run, to disable the touchpad while typing.

You should be able to add a shell script to /etc/mdm/Init to run your program – if not, at the very least you can add it to the /etc/mdm/Init/Default script.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Mint 17 by default installs Vixie cron. So you can put the following in your crontab:

```
@reboot /path/to/script
```

as described in `man 5 crontab`. `cron` is normally started before your login screen is initialized.