# Applications fail when started too early via Systemd--what dependency is required?

Tags: systemd

RPI 3b+, Debian Stretch

I want to start a Qt applicaton via systemd.  The app uses X and needs to open a display.

It always fails due to an Invalid MIT_MAGIC-COOKIE.  But then systemd restarts it (on-failure) and it runs fine.  ("Start APES Display Application is my Qt app--my grep picked up that "Light Display Manager has the same issue--fails first time, but succeeds on restart)

> pi@right-display:~ $ cat /var/log/syslog | grep Display
>
> Nov 16 10:43:26 right-display systemd[1]: Stopping Light Display
> Manager...
>
> Nov 16 10:43:40 right-display systemd[1]: Started Start APES Display
> Application.
>
> Nov 16 10:43:40 right-display systemd[1]: Starting Light Display
> Manager...
>
> Nov 16 10:43:41 right-display x11vnc[653]: 16/11/2023 10:43:41 ***
> XOpenDisplay failed. No -display or DISPLAY.
>
> Nov 16 10:43:41 right-display systemd[1]: Started Light Display
> Manager.
>
> Nov 16 10:43:42 right-display APES_Display[572]: QStandardPaths:
> XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-pi' Nov 16
> 10:43:44 right-display APES_Display[572]: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1
> keyqt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0 Nov
> 16 10:43:44 right-display APES_Display[572]: Could not connect to any
> X display.
>
> Nov 16 10:43:44 right-display systemd[1]: Display.service: Main
> process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
>
> Nov 16 10:43:44 right-display systemd[1]: Display.service: Unit
> entered failed state.
>
> Nov 16 10:43:44 right-display systemd[1]: Display.service: Failed with
> result 'exit-code'.
>
> Nov 16 10:43:45 right-display x11vnc[653]: 16/11/2023 10:43:45 ***
> XOpenDisplay of ":0" successful.
>
> Nov 16 10:44:02 right-display systemd[1]: Display.service: Service
> hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
>
> Nov 16 10:44:02 right-display systemd[1]: Stopped Start APES Display
> Application.
>
> Nov 16 10:44:02 right-display systemd[1]: Started Start APES Display
> Application.
>
> Nov 16 10:44:02 right-display APES_Display[1307]: QStandardPaths:
> XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-pi'

So, there must be some service that must be running before my app can open a display?  Or, do I need to create a "magic cookie" that seems to only be needed at boot time (starting the service manually always works)

How do I figure figure out what it is?

Comment: Does this help? https://superuser.com/questions/759759/writing-a-service-that-depends-on-xorg

Comment: Some other reading... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360537/cant-run-application-that-depends-on-x-as-a-systemd-service https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274402/run-a-command-at-startup-with-lightdm

Answer (score -1):

Probably the best is to create a systemd timer which will wait several seconds so until the display is operational and to make your service dependent on this timer. `OnBootSec=` is the timer option that should be used. From what we can see, the first failure appears between Starting LDM & Started LDM.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can make it work by adding a delay, but wouldn't it be better to add an After=unit so that there isn't a race condition?  The whole reason I'm switching to use systemd instead of starting using LXDE autostart is to eliminate race conditions that seem to cause sporadic issues.